# Creating DEM from stereo image pair?

Tags: qgis

I have pair of images: can I generate digital elevation model from that pair of images using QGIS? if it's possible, can anyone provide the way to do that?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool in the Orfeo-Toolbox called stereo framework. It might do what you want, and can be integrated into Qgis.

https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org//Applications/StereoFramework.html

But you can´t get a elevation model out of normal images. It will be at most a terrain model as you are only seeing the surface of the trees, buildings and so on.

Comment: thank you for your response i have cartosat stereo images of a place with those i want to create a DEM of that place. is there any direct plugins or functions atleast read those images bcoz i am new to this software

Answer (score 2):

I never try to create dem from stereo image pair but searching on web I found this post very interesting:
https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/elevation-maps-from-along-track-stereo-pairs/
You can use orfeo tools in qgis after setting it.
Look this QGSI documentation:
https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/processing/3rdParty.html

Comment: Thank you ,from many discussions i found that orfeo toolbox is tough and micmac tool also so is there any GUI based automatic DEM extraction from stereo images

Comment: thanks in advance is anybody know about FOSS4G. is it a tool like QGIS? if it is a tool is it possible to extract DEM from stereo images?